# Issue with "if" statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7, for-loop, with-statement

I have one file and I am trying to populate second file using its data in Python. While populating I am applying some `if` statements to manipulate one column in the 2nd file.

What I want to perform using these `if` statements: Check 31st column in file and if its value is `0` then return `0` value in 32nd column, if its value is blank then return `2` value in 32nd column and for every other non-zero and non-blank value return `1` value in 32nd column.

```
with open('DE_Combined_' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv", "rb") as in_file, open('DE_Combined_PD_' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv", "wb") as out_file:
   reader = csv.reader(in_file)
   writer = csv.writer(out_file)
   headers = next(reader, None)  # returns the headers or `None` if the input is empty
   if headers:
        writer.writerow(headers)
   for row in reader:
       if row[30] != 0:
           row[31] = 1
       else:
           row[31] = 0
       if row[30] == "":
           row[31] = 2
       writer.writerow(row)
```

This seems like a pretty straightforward problem but my output file is giving me the wrong results. It has `1` value in 32nd column for `0` value in 31st column. It should have been `0` in both columns. Although `2` value is coming against the `blank` value in 31st column.

Please help me in resolving this problem as I am clueless now after several attempts to find something wrong with the logic of `if` statements I have used.

Snippet of actual O/P: ( last 2 entries in both the rows are the columns concerned)

```
05/23/2013  May 2013    2013    4   2   Thursday    UK  O2  £   NOKIA   100 NOKIA 100   Smartphone  Symbian NA          9.99            N       Pay & Go    Pay & Go                    0.64222 0   1
05/23/2013  May 2013    2013    4   2   Thursday    UK  O2  £   NOKIA   100 NOKIA 100   Smartphone  Symbian NA  Pink        9.99            N       Pay & Go    Pay & Go                    0.64222 0   1
```

I/P Snippet:(First 2 rows) ( Last 2 columns are the concerned columns)

```
Date,Month,Fiscal_Year,Calendar_Year,FY_Quarter,CY_Quarter,Day_of_Week,Geography,MO,Currency,Device_OEM,Device_Name,GDN,Device_Type,Device_OS,Device_Franchise,Device_Color,Device_Storage_in_GB,Device_Price,Device_Monthly_Price,Additional,Device_Refurb,Plan_COMPARISON,Plan_Name,Plan_Contract_Length,Plan_Monthly_Price,Plan_Data_in_GB,Plan_Minutes,Plan_Texts,Exchange_Rate_vs_1USD,Difference,Difference_Flag
05/23/2013,May,2013,2013,4,2,Thursday,UK,O2,£,NOKIA,100,NOKIA 100,Smartphone,Symbian,NA,,,9.99,,,N,,Pay & Go,Pay & Go,,,,,0.64222,0.0,
05/23/2013,May,2013,2013,4,2,Thursday,UK,O2,£,NOKIA,100,NOKIA 100,Smartphone,Symbian,NA,Pink,,9.99,,,N,,Pay & Go,Pay & Go,,,,,0.64222,0.0,
```

Comment: add a `print row` just after the for-loop, does it look like you expect it to do? Or update your question with the actual input. Right now we can do nothing but guess...

Comment: have you considered splitting your read and write functions? first read the input csv, populate a list with the data you want to write, manipulate as desired, then write the ouput file. i am thinking something is going on between the `row[30] != 0 `and `row[31] = 1`

Comment: @multiphrenic Can you help me in devise that approach? I am very new to programming

Comment: the `O/P` part contains 28 and 29 columns. Is that part the input or the output? We need to input to be able to help you...

Comment: it looks like 28 or 29 because of empty columns present in the row.

Comment: if it is the input, the data isn't in csv-format which require it to be separated with a comma (`,`) (or another delimiter)

Comment: last 2 entries in the output rows snippet are the columns concerned.

Comment: we don't care about the output, we would like to see you input-data, please!

Comment: @FredrikPihl I think I have found the problem, I opened the csv file in notepad to look at the entries and found out that entries are mentioned as '0.0' and I also have to write my conditions according to that.

Comment: good for you, but if you had posted you input 50 minutes ago, your problem whould have been solved 50 minutes ago...

Comment: @atams, I'd still recommend splitting your tasks, even if you found the cause of your errors. If you have any other problems, you will be able to peek into your data structures, something not possible with the way you've written your code. See answer below.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Sorry for that, I have attached the i/p now. I tried using 0.0 in the code but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change your logic to this (remember, everything is strings unless you transform them using `int()`, `float()` etc.)

```
for row in reader:
    print "'%s'" % row[30]
    if float(row[30]) != 0:
        row[31] = '1'
    else:
        row[31] = '0'
    if row[30] == "":
        row[31] = 2
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I get this output:

```
05/23/2013,May,2013,2013,4,2,Thursday,UK,O2,£,NOKIA,100,NOKIA 100,Smartphone,Symbian,NA,,,9.99,,,N,,Pay & Go,Pay & Go,,,,,0.64222,0.0,0
05/23/2013,May,2013,2013,4,2,Thursday,UK,O2,£,NOKIA,100,NOKIA 100,Smartphone,Symbian,NA,Pink,,9.99,,,N,,Pay & Go,Pay & Go,,,,,0.64222,0.0,0
```

where the last elements are 0; that was the problem, right?

Comment: What I want is 0 in last column for values which are 0.0 or 0 in second last column and 1 in last column if values are non-zero and non-blank. For blanks I want 2 in last column

Comment: Issue resolved, I converted it to float. Got the hint from your comment. I used `float(row[30]) != 0` and it worked for whole file

Comment: Can you make the change in your answer using this line `float(row[30]) != 0` As it will help the other users better.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

*Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No automatic data type conversion is performed.*

Perhaps your `if row[30] != 0` should be changed to `if row[30] != "0"`

Comment: This method works partially, around half of my rows are still showing `1` against the `0` value.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your tasks into functions that read, manipulate, then write the data.

To read your table into a list:

```
def importCSV(fname):
    """ Returns a tuple using a CSV as input. First tuple is the
    header. 
    Second tuple is a dictionary with all the data.
    """
    data = []
    with open(fname, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = reader.fieldnames
        for lines in reader:
            data.append(lines)
        return (header, data)

header, data = importCSV('myfile.csv')
```

now manipulate your data:

```
for line in data:
    do something to line...
....
```

then write your data:

```
def CreateCSVFromList(header, source, outputfile):
    """Creates a CSV from a 2D List.
    Header should be a simple list for each column in the resulting list.
    Source is the list.
    Output file is what is written. Include the .csv extension please.
    No error-checking is being done at the moment.
    """
    import csv
    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in source:
            writer.writerow(row)


CreateCSVFromList(header, data, 'output.csv')
```

Comment: I tried using this and this part for populating the last column `     row[31] = 1
     if row[30] == "0.0":
       row[31] = 0
     if row[30] == "0":
       row[31] = 0
     if row[30] == "":
       row[31] = 2`
` It is giving me this error `    if row[30] == "0.0":
KeyError: 30`

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Did you create a header and data using `importCSV()`? Did you give the results from that function a name, like header, data?

If so, you will have a list called `data`. You can then modify items in that list as you wish. If you wanted to validate the 30th item in that list and replace the 31st item with 1, you could do: `if data[29] == "0.0": data[30] = 1`

Comment: Turns out, I should use float() and int() while comparing numbers. float() resolved my problem but thanks for your answer as I know now a new approach to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_buffer = ''
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 31:
        if row == ['']:             #check whether 31st row is empty
            _buffer = 2               #if that's true write `2`to line 32

        elif row == ['0']:      #if that's false check wheter 31st row = 0
            _buffer = 1           #if true, write `1`to line 32

        else:                 
            _buffer = 1 

    if reader.line_num == 32:
        row = _buffer

    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Nopes, didn't work. Can there be issue with the csv file processing?

Comment: I guess the problem is the `for`loop. You don't have to scale the whole file just to check for one row! Try something like `if reader[30]==""` ...

Comment: I am populating 2nd file in `wb` mode row by row. How do I perform this check and change outside the for loop?

Comment: @atams - please update your question with some lines from your actual input; without it we can only guess!

Comment: That's because you're not using the same input as the OP, apparently the data is in format "0.0". OP didn't describe that though...

Comment: `writer.writerow(row)
Error: sequence expected` I am getting this error. ANd I have both type of entries in the data `0` and `0.0`